# При уменьшении масштаба съезжает меню

Tags: html, css

Ситуация следующая:
Есть контейнер с кнопками. И контейнер и кнопки имеют фиксированный размер. При уменьшении масштаба в браузере, начинают выезжать кнопки вниз, как будто не помещаются.

Вопросы:

1. Почему?
2. Как исправить?

Comment: пример кода было бы неплохо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делай так: определяешь ширину клиентского окна сперва. А потом определяешь согласно этому расположение элементов.

Я сам сделал так: определяю сперва ширину окна. Потом вычисляю местонахождение главного блока. Например если он посередине и ты дал ему ширину 1000 пикселей, то от всей ширины отнимаешь 1000, разделяешь на 2 и получаешь начальную точку. А отсюда уже сам дальше понял думаю.

Comment: что за бред? Мне не надо позиционировать главный блок. Он стоит на нужном месте. Кнопки внутри съезжают.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть у вас используется position:relative

Comment: нет. Только float у кнопок